# Tamerlane and Operation Barbarossa

Tags: soviet-union

While going through Tamerlane's article on Wikipedia I found

> It is also said that when Gerasimov exhumed Timur's body, an additional inscription inside the casket was found reading, "Who ever opens my tomb, shall unleash an invader more terrible than I." In any case, two days after Gerasimov begun the exhumation, Adolf Hitler launched Operation Barbarossa, the largest military invasion of all time, upon the USSR.

The claim was ftom  [Mark Stratton's article](http://www.independent.co.uk/travel/asia/uzbekistan-on-the-bloody-trail-of-tamerlane-407300.html)

Have there been more sources or works appreciating the irony, or presenting it atleast? Or is it just pseudo history?

Comment: It might be argued that Timur was rather more terrible than Hitler.

Comment: He was in power roughly 4 times as long - Does one calculate *terribleness per year* as a simple *arithmetic mean* or is a more complex measure warranted?

Comment: A lame curse if the Soviets could beat off this terrible invader.

Comment: @Pieter Geerkens: But Timur also had a much smaller population on which to exercise his terribility (if I can use the term).  Do we figure terror in absolute numbers, or by percentage of population killed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Wikipedia article on [M. Gerasimov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikhail_Mikhaylovich_Gerasimov) requests a citation. The source cited in the [Tamerlane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timur) article is a news article from 2006 that mentions the prophecy as hearsay. Unless something else comes out, we have no proof that this isn't fabricated.